# insert data in a wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, post

I'm developing a WordPress plugin which is responsible for getting data from an external HTML form and then inserts it in the database. My form code is:

```
    <html>
   <body>
    <form action = "http://wp.istic.online/wp-content/plugins/news-apps/index.php" method = "POST">
         Name: <input type = "text" name = "name" />

         <input type = "submit" />
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

My plugin code is:

```
    <?php
```

register($_POST['name']);
    register($_POST['name']);

```
function register($name) {

    global $wpdb;
$wpdb->insert(
    'gcm_tokens',
    array(
        'token' => $name
    ),
    array(
        '%s'
    )
);

}
```

The data is not inserted however when I try to echo the `$name` variable it works perfectly. But when I try to echo it after the insert function it's not working.

Any help please?

Comment: you forgot to call the register function

Comment: i called it but i forgot to write it in my question , sorry

Comment: ok, please update the question then. But anyway, why are you using the wpdb class instead of inserting directly? This code doesn't really have anything to do with wordpress does it?

Comment: no it's a wordpress plugin code that's why i am using the wpdb class

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_nonce_field() like below

```
<form>
/*
Your code
*/
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>

</form>
```

Comment: my form is not a part of my WordPress website it's on an external web page

Comment: you can include wp-blog-header to use WordPress function

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have correct db prefix, correct table name and you can get $POST variable correctly.

I tried your code by call register('Test'); and It works.